# Subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$: Stuck on closed under addition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$S=\left \{ \begin{bmatrix}
x_{1}\\ x_{2}
\\ 
x_{3}
\end{bmatrix} ; x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}=x_{3}^{2} \right \}$$

Closed under addition:

Let $\vec{y}=\begin{bmatrix}
y_{1}\\y_{2}
\\ 
y{3}
\end{bmatrix}\in S$ such that $y_{1}^{2}+y_{2}^{2}=y_{3}^2$

$\vec{x}+\vec{y}=\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1}+y_{1}\\x_{2}+y_{2}
\\ 
x_{3}+y_{}3
\end{bmatrix}$ and for S to be a subspace:
$(x_{1}+y_{1})^2+(x_{2}+y_{2})^2=(x_{3}+y_{3})^2$

Expands to:
$x_{1}^{2}+2x_{1}y_{1}+y_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+2x_{2}y_{2}+y_{2}^{2}=x_{3}^{2}+2x_{3}y_{3}+y_{3}^{2}$

Rearranged:
$(x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+y_{1}^{2}+y_{2}^{2})+2x_{1}y_{1}+2x_{2}y_{2} = x_{3}^{2}+2x_{3}y_{3}+y_{3}^{2}$

Simplified:
$(x_{3}^{2}+y_{3}^{2})+2x_{1}y_{1}+2x_{2}y_{2} = (x_{3}^{2}+y_{3}^{2}) + 2x_{3}y_{3}$

$$x_{1}y_{1}+x_{2}y_{2}=x_{3}y_{3}$$

and I'm not sure where to carry on from there or if I'm trying to prove something impossible.
Thanks

Comment: Hint: try choosing an $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ that meet the condition. For your choice of $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$, is it true that $x_1y_1+x_2y_2=x_3y_3$?

Comment: And another way to look at the problem: If $S$ were a subspace, then any two Pythagorean triples could be added componentwise to get a new Pythagorean triple. Is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $3^2+4^2=5^2$, and $5^2+12^2=13^2$, but $8^2+16^2\not=18^2$. Can you use this to show that S is not closed under addition?